# I have added custom claims, but they are not getting added into token

Tags: authentication, .net-core, authorization, identityserver4

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uioco.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tChrV.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/19gcN.png)

I am doing this but still I'm not able to add custom claims.

I have tried above code but still can't able to get in token as well as using `HttpContextAccessor`.

I am not able to get the custom claims.

Comment: I have a set of blog posts about troubleshooting claim problems here https://nestenius.se/2023/03/28/missing-openid-connect-claims-in-asp-net-core/